# store a function in a variable. Why dont work? python

Tags: python, python-3.x

```
def triangle_area(base, height):    
    area = (1.0 / 2) * base * height
    return area

a1 = triangle_area(3, 8)
print a1
```

SyntaxError: invalid syntax   (in a1)  why?

Answer (score 1):

If you're using Python 3, `print` is a function, not a statement like it was in Python 2. You need to put parentheses around `a1` in your last line to make it a function call:

```
print(a1)
```

Comment: The code you've shown works for me, once the `print` issue is taken care of. If you're having an issue still, you'll need to provide more information about it. Can you edit to include the full traceback?